# best practice to count record in MySQL + PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, query-optimization

I want to check weather number of record > 15 for a condition.

What is best practice to speed up the query?

1)

```
$query="SELECT `id` FROM `table` WHERE `name`='$name' AND `usage` > '$limit'";
$result=mysql_query($query);       
if(mysql_num_rows($result) >15) 
{
    //do task

}
```

2)

```
$query="SELECT COUNT(1) AS 'cnt' FROM `table` WHERE `name`='$name' AND `usage` > '$limit'";

$result=mysql_query($query); 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

if($row['cnt'] >15) 
{
    //do task

}
```

3) any other best way?

Comment: The second one all the way.

Comment: [`MySQL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) (`mysql_*` functions) extension is [***deprecated***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). I suggest to use [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (`mysqli_*` functions) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: #3. SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS

Comment: What was faster/more efficient when you looked at the EXPLAIN plans and when you tested it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [my sql best practice with php for counting rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12189147/my-sql-best-practice-with-php-for-counting-rows). Another [interesting resource here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761215/count-from-a-table-but-stop-counting-at-a-certain-number).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, use COUNT( * ) instead of COUNT(fieldname) since mysql is optimised for COUNT( * ).

Second, if the table is very large then ensure that you have indexes on the columns in the WHERE clause to speed up execution.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I only check if no of record in >15. so i think it is best to put LIMIT 16 in the query

Answer (score 0):

u can use

```
$query="SELECT COUNT(id) as cnt FROM `table` WHERE `name`='$name' AND `usage` > '$limit'";

$result=mysql_query($query); 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

if($row['cnt'] >15) 
{
    //do task

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$query="SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `id` FROM `table` WHERE 
         `name`='$name' AND `usage` > '$limit'";
$result=mysql_query($query);       
if(mysql_num_rows($result) >15) 
{
    //do task
}
```

For total rows, use

```
$resultTotal=mysql_query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()");
```

Read this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

also [Which is fastest? SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS FROM `table`, or SELECT COUNT(*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186588/which-is-fastest-select-sql-calc-found-rows-from-table-or-select-count)

Answer (score 0):

you can check it yourself for both the codes you posted in this fashion:

```
$mt=microtime(true);
/* your code */
$qt=microtime(true)-$mt;
print "time elapsed: " . number_format($et) . "s\n";
```

i think for a single time use the second one would be economic but if u have to iterate over the values a prepared statement will be better.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, second is better. at first query, `Mysql` try to consider some system resources for fetching and keeping the `id` column as a result set like `$result`, specially in a large amount of data, it will be an important reason for getting more time to execute query.
But at the second query , it just assign a counter variable like `cnt` for showing counting records.

Also note, `COUNT(id)` does not count `NULL` values. Then if `id` can be set to `NULL` by definition, it's better to use `COUNT(*)` or based on your choice to counting `NULL` value or not.